# How to create a negative space with a 3d model?

Tags: workflow, topology, photogrammetry, remesh

I have had some issues with cleaning up photogrammetry scans and ending up with the outside clean but lots of strange internal geometry that can be hard to get at and tidy up.

I can always clean up the scans with Zbrush Zremesher, but I would like to know how to do this in Blender.

I'm wondering if I can take a photogrammetry model and put a shape like a cube over it, and then delete my model from inside the cube leaving a negative space inside of the cube that I could then turn into a 3d model with a single sealed surface?

What would be a suitable workflow to approach this?

Comment: Try the Remesh modifier?

Comment: BTW, that negative space thing would be inverting the normals, which are data for each face that say which way it outward. It could theoretically work, but then in this case you’d just have the same problem backwards.